# how to use np.argmax calculate the max difference between elements in one vector?

Tags: python, numpy

like this to get the max difference between elements in one vector, but this example always output 0

```
s = [1,2,3,5]
print(np.argmax(s[i+1]-s[i] for i in range(len(s)-1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass a generator. Pass a list, i.e add square brackets around in `argmax`:

```
np.argmax([s[i+1]-s[i] for i in range(len(s)-1)])
```

Comment: Also, you can just do `np.diff(s).argmax()`